# Add a custom row with displaytag

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

Is there a way of adding a custom row(s) to the top of a displaytag table?

There is a way of adding a footer via `display:footer`,  but why no header?

Comment: What sort of line do you want to add to the top of the table?

Comment: I'm reworking some legacy code and the current table has an extra row with some instructions.
Wouldn't mind keeping that if I can to keep the punter happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this tag library is only to display and export a sorted list of object.

Here is the [Tag Reference Sheet](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html) of the project

You have an other way to customize your table with a [property file](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/configuration.html).

If you want to add something else to the current tag library you should override classes of the displaytag project in order to make it possible.